# Need PHP Mailer Form with File Attachment script to send form information with or without attachment

Tags: php, email, attachment

I'm having some trouble trying to get my script to send a file attachment with the information collected from the form. I used [PHP Mailer Form with File Attachment](http://designbyelle.com.au/journal/2008/04/23/php-mailer-form-with-file-attachment/) and modified to fit my specification. So far it will send the form information without the attached image but when I upload an image it will only send the attachment and no other information from the form. I need it to be able to send the form information with or without an attachment. I'm a beginner with php so I'm not sure why its doing this.

Here is my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $sendTo = '<myemail@somesite.com';
    $subject = 'Request';
    $from = $_POST['email_address'];

    // Allowed file types. add file extensions WITHOUT the dot.
    $allowtypes=array("jpg", "png", "gif");

    // Require a file to be attached: false = Do not allow attachments true = allow only 1 file to be attached
    $requirefile="true";

    // Maximum file size for attachments in KB NOT Bytes for simplicity. MAKE SURE your php.ini can handel it,
    // post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, file_uploads, max_execution_time!
    // 2048kb = 2MB,       1024kb = 1MB,     512kb = 1/2MB etc..
    $max_file_size="5120";

    $errors = array(); //Initialize error array

    //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
    if((!empty($_FILES["attachment"])) && ($_FILES['attachment']['error'] == 0)) {
            // basename -- Returns filename component of path
            $filename = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
            $filesize=$_FILES['attachment']['size'];
            $max_bytes=$max_file_size*5120;

            //Check if the file type uploaded is a valid file type. 
            if (!in_array($ext, $allowtypes)) {
                $errors[]="Invalid extension for your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong>";

        // check the size of each file
        } elseif($filesize > $max_bytes) {
                $errors[]= "Your file: <strong>".$filename."</strong> is to big. Max file size is ".$max_file_size."kb.";
            }

    } // if !empty FILES

        // send an email
        // Obtain file upload vars
        $fileatt      = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $fileatt_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
        $fileatt_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

        // Headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$from = $_POST['email_address'];

        // create a boundary string. It must be unique
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        // Add the headers for a file attachment
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

        // Add a multipart boundary above the plain message
        $message ="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
        $message.="--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $message.="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
        $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $message .= "Name: \t\t".$_POST['name']."\n";
        $message .= "Email: \t\t".$_POST['email_address']."\n";
        if($_POST['phone_number'] != ""){
            $message .= "Phone: \t\t".$_POST['phone']."\n";

        $message .= "Date: \t\t".$_POST['full_date']."\n";
        }
        $message .= "\n";
        if($_POST['additional_info'] != ""){
            $message .= "Additional Information: \n".$_POST['additional_info']."\n";
        }
        if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
        // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
        $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
        $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
        fclose($file);

        // Base64 encode the file data
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

        // Add file attachment to the message
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                  //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                  $data . "\n\n" .
                  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
        }

        // Send the completed message
        mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);

        header("Location: complete.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: with out code, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done to send a mail with an attachment. Some of the code is mine and some of it has been taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php. This code has been tried and tested so, it should work. Also see if sendmail is installed. If on linux ubuntu system try sudo apt-get install sendmail to install it.

File Name: index.php

```
    <?php
    if( $_POST || $_FILES )
    {
            // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
            // Here 
            $from = "someone@somewhere.com";
            $to = "someone_else@somewhere_else.com";
            $subject = "Mail with Attachment";
            $message = "This is the message body and to it I will append the attachments.";
            $headers = "From: $from";

            // boundary
            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

            // headers for attachment
            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

            // multipart boundary
            $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
            fixFilesArray($_FILES['attachment']);
            foreach ($_FILES['attachment'] as $position => $file) 
            {
                    // should output array with indices name, type, tmp_name, error, size
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    $fp     = @fopen($file['tmp_name'],"rb");
                    $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($file['tmp_name']));
                    @fclose($fp);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file['name']."\"\n"."Content-Description: ".$file['name']."\n" ."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$file['name']."\";size=".$file['size'].";\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            }
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
            $returnpath = "-f" . $from;
            $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
            if($ok){ return 1; } else { return 0; }
    }
    //This function will correct file array from $_FILES[[file][position]] to $_FILES[[position][file]] .. Very important

    function fixFilesArray(&$files)
    {
            $names = array( 'name' => 1, 'type' => 1, 'tmp_name' => 1, 'error' => 1, 'size' => 1);

            foreach ($files as $key => $part) {
                    // only deal with valid keys and multiple files
                    $key = (string) $key;
                    if (isset($names[$key]) && is_array($part)) {
                            foreach ($part as $position => $value) {
                                    $files[$position][$key] = $value;
                            }
                            // remove old key reference
                            unset($files[$key]);
                    }
            }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="attachment[]"><br/>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

By the way I would like to apologize for using sendmail since it is a bit slow. I will try to post a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: How can i limit this script to accept only certain extension like .PDF and .DOC/.DOCX? Thanks