# Sending Form Data with Attachment

Tags: php, forms, email, attachment

Ok, I've gotten the attachment working in the email and it's being sent correctly thanks to this bit that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8410569/3897654)

What this is getting me is an email with an attachment, but none of the other form data is being injected into the email. I'm sure it's a problem with the syntax that I'm using, but I con't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at about a billion other form examples that I've found here (and other less helpful nooks and crannies of the web)

Also, before the downvotes pour in, I realize I haven't done any sort of validation yet, and I'm not forwarding the user to a success URL after the message has been sent. I'm just trying to get the script working the way I think it should before I start going nuts over validating it.

Here is the html for my form:

```
  <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" enctype="multipart/form-data"
   method="POST" action="mail.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>About You</legend>

    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-3">
            <label for="street">Street Address</label>
            <input id="street" name="street" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input id="city" name="city" type="text">
        </div>


        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
            <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required>
        </div>

    </div>
     <legend>About Your Company</legend>
    <div class="pure-g" >
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="companyname">Company Name</label>
            <input id="companyname" name="companyname" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="companysize"># of Employees?</label>
            <input id="companysize" name="companysize" type="number" required>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="companywebsite">Website</label>
            <input id="companywebsite" name="companywebsite" type="url" required placeholder="eg www.mysite.com">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-1">
            <label for="companylogo">Upload your Logo</label>
            <input id="companylogo" type="file" name="attachment[]" >
        </div>

    </div>



    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

And here is the php from 'mail.php'

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ //check form inputs
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $street = $_POST['street'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
        $companysize = $_POST['companysize'];
        $companywebsite = $_POST['companywebsite'];
    }

if( $_POST || $_FILES )
{
        // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
        // Here 
        $from = "host@notareal.com";
        $to = "setmeup@notareal.com";
        $subject = "Setup Request from Free Setup Form";
        $message = $firstname.$lastname.$email.$street.$city.$zip.$phone.$companyname.$companysize.$companywebsite;
        $headers = "From: $from";

        // boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        // headers for attachment
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

        // multipart boundary
        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
        fixFilesArray($_FILES['attachment']);
        foreach ($_FILES['attachment'] as $position => $file) 
        {
                // should output array with indices name, type, tmp_name, error, size
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $fp     = @fopen($file['tmp_name'],"rb");
                $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($file['tmp_name']));
                @fclose($fp);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file['name']."\"\n"."Content-Description: ".$file['name']."\n" ."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$file['name']."\";size=".$file['size'].";\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        }
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
        $returnpath = "-f" . $from;
        $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
        if($ok){ return 1; } else { return 0; }
}
//This function will correct file array from $_FILES[[file][position]] to $_FILES[[position][file]] .. Very important

function fixFilesArray(&$files)
{
        $names = array( 'name' => 1, 'type' => 1, 'tmp_name' => 1, 'error' => 1, 'size' => 1);

        foreach ($files as $key => $part) {
                // only deal with valid keys and multiple files
                $key = (string) $key;
                if (isset($names[$key]) && is_array($part)) {
                        foreach ($part as $position => $value) {
                                $files[$position][$key] = $value;
                        }
                        // remove old key reference
                        unset($files[$key]);
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Name your submit button. Your conditional statement relies on it.

Comment: Thanks Fred- really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$_POST["submit"]` is never set - your button doesn't have a name.

Comment: If ever there were a [coincidence in time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071075/sending-form-data-with-attachment#comment39004529_25071075); this would be it ;)